# MySQL 8 cte just hangs

Tags: mysql

I am using mySQL 8.0.22 and phpmyadmin 4.9.5. Table tb is MEMORY engine, which is preloaded on every mysqld start using --init-file queries.

```
SELECT
  t0.`specificID`,tb.`startfund`,tb.`endfund`,
  tb.`num_IFTs`,t0.`mean`,t0.`SD`,t0.`min`,t0.`max`,
  t0.`mean_over_SD`,t0.`mean-SD`,t0.`PNR`,t0.`beatG`,t0.`beatF`,
  t0.`beatC`,t0.`beatS`,t0.`beatI`,t0.`deltaG`,t0.`deltaF`,
  t0.`deltaC`,t0.`deltaS`,t0.`deltaI`,tb.`timeG`,tb.`timeF`,
  tb.`timeC`,tb.`timeS`,tb.`timeI` 
FROM `strategy_stats_0420_jan` AS t0 
LEFT JOIN `strategies_memory_jan` AS tb ON t0.specificID = tb.specificID
ORDER BY `mean` DESC;
```

This works fine. It returns in 0.0x seconds.

However, running this next query with cte doesn't work at all. It hangs indefinitely. Eventually I give up and reboot mysqld. I simplified the query for testing purposes, normally it is several queries with UNION ALL:

```
WITH
cte1 AS (
  SELECT
    t0.`specificID`,tb.`startfund`,tb.`endfund`,
    tb.`num_IFTs`,t0.`mean`,t0.`SD`,t0.`min`,t0.`max`,
  t0.`mean_over_SD`,t0.`mean-SD`,t0.`PNR`,t0.`beatG`,t0.`beatF`,
  t0.`beatC`,t0.`beatS`,t0.`beatI`,t0.`deltaG`,t0.`deltaF`,
  t0.`deltaC`,t0.`deltaS`,t0.`deltaI`,tb.`timeG`,tb.`timeF`,
  tb.`timeC`,tb.`timeS`,tb.`timeI` 
  FROM `strategy_stats_0420_jan` AS t0 
  LEFT JOIN `strategies_memory_jan` AS tb ON t0.specificID = tb.specificID
) SELECT * FROM cte1 ORDER BY `mean` DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the `ORDER BY` outside the CTE. It doesn't make sente to have it inside.

For example:

```
WITH
cte1 AS (
  SELECT
    t0.`specificID`,tb.`startfund`,tb.`endfund`,
    tb.`num_IFTs`,t0.`mean`,t0.`SD`,t0.`min`,t0.`max`,
  t0.`mean_over_SD`,t0.`mean-SD`,t0.`PNR`,t0.`beatG`,t0.`beatF`,
  t0.`beatC`,t0.`beatS`,t0.`beatI`,t0.`deltaG`,t0.`deltaF`,
  t0.`deltaC`,t0.`deltaS`,t0.`deltaI`,tb.`timeG`,tb.`timeF`,
  tb.`timeC`,tb.`timeS`,tb.`timeI` 
  FROM `strategy_stats_0420_jan` AS t0 
  LEFT JOIN `strategies_memory_jan` AS tb ON t0.specificID = tb.specificID
)
SELECT * 
FROM cte1
ORDER BY `mean` DESC
```

Comment: I moved the ORDER BY like Impaler said. That makes sense but it did not resolve the issue. I ran the same cte query from the command line and it works fine. This appears to be a phpmyadmin problem. Thanks